# Why isn't this "appcmd add backup "PreMigration.$date" working?

Tags: powershell, iis

How can I pass the date to the `appcmd`?

```psh
$date = get-date
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add backup PreMigration.$date
```

> ERROR ( hresult:8007007b, message:Command execution failed.
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. )

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to [format your date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so that it doesn't contain characters that are invalid in a path.

```psh
$date = get-date -Format 'yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm'
$appcmd = "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd"
$args = @("add", "backup", "PreMigration.$date")
& $appcmd $args
```

Right now, this will essentially run the command

```
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add backup PreMigration.2015.05.15.15.56
```

Comment: Thank you.  I submitted that too early.  I think I am on the right path in formatting the date to not have spaces...  ideally I'd have a format like yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm 

Does that look right? for an output of premigration.2015.05.15.1400.21  ??

Comment: I updated my answer.  You were definitely on the right track.  I just updated the format of `get-date`.  Give that a shot.

Comment: BACKUP object "PreMigration.2015.05.15.17.06" added  - YOU ROCK!  

So if you would be kind enough - could you help me understand the last two lines in laymans terms?  I work better that way.  LOL  Thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely!  `&` tells PowerShell to execute a command (as opposed to, say, write out a string or treat it as an object). `$appcmd` is the path to the executable.  `&` adds arguments using an array, so we just treat each word in the argument as an element of an array. Check [this](http://ss64.com/ps/call.html) out for more info, or search 'powershell call operator'.

Comment: Nope, just a pretty standard name for that variable.